# how to get the value of the variable from the previous seconds of a countdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript

how to store and use the value of a variable from the previous seconds of a time interval countdown ?
the time interval is something like this

```
setInterval(function() {
 // processing of stuff inside
},1000);

let's say e.g
a = 10, b = 2, c = 3

the current time is 18:00:01 and a = 10, b = 2, c = 3
on the next second is 18:00:02 a = 10, b = 14, c = 51
on the third second is 18:00:03, a = 13 , b = 2, c = 32
on the fourth second, the time is 18:00:04, a = 13 , b = 5, c = 23
```

notice the variable a ..it uses the previous second's value
I know another way to solve my problem, it's by storing the previous second value in a text file.
but that is very inefficient as the countdown is too fast..I should be able to store it in a variaable ? 
what should be the logic inside the time interval loop ?

Comment: What's the logic behind `a = 10, b = 14, c = 51`, `a = 13 , b = 2, c = 32`, etc?

Comment: ignore the variable b and c... there is some math computation that allows it to change the variable a...please ignore variable b and c...i just need to know what approach should I do in order to store the variable a  previous value and re-use it on the next second

Comment: You can't use another variable like `prevA`?

Comment: can you please atleast help put your sample code inside the time interval..

Comment: This reads like a logic problem.  Nothing about this question is telling me that you need to use jQuery to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
let a = 10, prevA = a

setInterval(function() {
  console.clear()
  console.log("prevA has value", prevA) 
  a+= 20 // To observe slowly
  console.log("a has value", a)
  prevA = a
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Store variable a's prior value in another variable.

```js
    let aPrior;
    setInterval(function () {
      a = myFunction(aPrior);
      aPrior = a;
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: this, straight to the point answer.instead of debating...thank you

Comment: don't be too hard on the others and their comments, sasori - they were not making unreasonable observations.